# Can an MN27 alkaline battery power my 12 V, 0.16 A motor?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, motor, capacity

I have two motors in parallel rated for 12 V at 0.16 A.

They generate a small 14.4 pounds (64 N) of force combined at a slow speed of 30 mm/s.

The motors open and close a door for this project.
The power source must be light and can't be more than 0.5 pounds, so that is why I'm looking for a small power source.

I only need the motors to run, opening and closing the door for about 15-30 seconds during the project's active time span.

The [Duracell Mn27](https://www.duracell.com/en-us/product/mn27-alkaline-battery/) can deliver 12 V at 20 mAh according to their website.

According to my math, this singular battery should be able to theoretically open and close the door continuously for 8 minutes before dying. Obviously, the voltage won't be constant during this process.

Is this tiny battery the optimal choice for this project? Or will I run into a lot of issues and I should look elsewhere? If the latter, what would you recommend?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Watch out... this cell is rated for 20 mAh **_when connected to a constant 20kOhm load_**, during which time the voltage drops from ~12v to a cutoff of ~6v... that's ~500uA (ish, depending on the voltage). The [datasheet](https://www.duracell.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/MN27_0620191.pdf) doesn't mention ESR, but based on the given characteristics, and typical applications, you may not be able to supply 160mA (or 320mA?), and you almost certainly won't get 12v for long!

Comment: @Attie Thanks a ton! Yea I need only 0.160 mA. based on your comment, I don't think I want to rely on that cell anymore. Do you think you could direct me in the right direction as far as what cells/power supplies exist out there that I could purchase for this project?

Comment: You have a few options, of which lithium is popular these days.  64N*30mm/s ~= 2W. Thankfully with .5 lb of battery, that's about 10W/kg, an achievable amount.  *30 sec and that's 60 J per.  With .5 lb that's at least 300 J/kg and that's where it gets rough.

Comment: The A27 battery weights 4.4g, while you have a budget of >200g. Sounds like you have some room for a better choice.

Comment: Alkaline batteries will not supply a constant voltage across the entire lifespan, and will degrade below 12V before dying. Lithium batteries would be a better choice, with the added benefit of rechargeability. Additionally, when you ask a question regarding specific parts, it is better to include the datasheet as it has important information which can help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a MN27 Alkaline Battery Power my 12V 0.16A Motor?

No, no way this tiny set of 8 coin cells can deliver 160mA at 12V.

There is a thing called "internal impedance" of a battery. For the A27/MN27 type of batteries the internal impedance is about 50 Ohms (as I just measured on A23 battery, which is slightly bigger than A27, since I failed to find any real specifications on the batteries). The load of 1K makes a drop from 12.6V to 12.0V. This is a 12mA load.

Therefore a load of 160mA will drop the battery's terminal voltage down to about 3V. 3V won't spin your motor.

For your project and weight limits you may want to make your own battery out of 10 [NiMH cells of AAAA](https://www.eblofficial.com/products/aaaa-batteries) size, total 7g x10 = 70g, with ~300mA discharge for ~1 hour. Maybe you can find smaller cells if you need only 8 min of runtime.